# Show that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges where $a_1 = 1$ and $a_n = \sqrt{1+ a_{n-1}}$ for all $n \geq 2$. With MCT and induction.

Tags: solution-verification

Not only will I prove this, but I will further use the property of subsequences to find the limit of the sequence. 
1. We must show that $a_n$ is monotone increasing or decreasing, and 2. that $a_n$ is bounded (above or below). 
By inspection, $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = \sqrt{2}$, $a_3 = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$,...
My claim is that the sequence is monotone increasing.

Proof: (by induction on n).

Base case: $n = 1$. Then $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = \sqrt{2}$. Since $1<2$, it follows that $\sqrt{1} = 1  < \sqrt{2}$. Thus $a_1 < a_2$

Inductive step: Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be given and suppose that $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$. [Goal: $a_{n+2} \geq a_{n+1}$]. Then since $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$, $1+a_{n+1} \geq 1+a_n$ and thus $a_{n+2}=\sqrt{1+a_{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{1+a_n} = a_{n+1}$.

Now we need to show that $a_n$ is bounded above. 
Proof: (by induction on n)

Base case: $n = 1$, so $a_1 = 1 < 2$.

Inductive Step: Fix $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose $a_n < 2$. [Goal: $a_{n+1} < 2$]. Then, $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+a_n} < \sqrt{1+2} = \sqrt{3} < 2$. This is because $4>3$ and thus $2>\sqrt{3}$. Thus $a_{n+1} < 2$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore by the MCT, $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges.

Well, what does it exactly converge too?
Let us say that $a_n$ converges to $L$ where $L\in \mathbb{R}$. We can look at the $a_n$ term to get a better idea. Since, $a_n = \sqrt{1+ a_{n-1}}$, $a_n^2 = 1+a_{n-1}$. Since $a_n$ converges to $L$, it follows that all of its subsequences also converge to $L$ i.e. $a_{n-1}$. Therefore we can rewrite this equation in terms of L. Thus we have that $L^2 = 1 + L$ and that $L^2 - L -1 = 0$. We can use the quadratic formula to obtain the solution that $L = \frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Let me know what you think of this proof! I am not quite sure this L is correct, but let me know about your thoughts. Just trying to get ready for my intro to math proof class final tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, convergence of the same sequence was asked about at [Proving a sequence converges to the golden ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504233/602049).

Comment: Thanks, I was not looking for the solution though, more so some constructive criticism of my proof.

Comment: You're welcome. I realize you were looking for comments about your proof, which is why I stated "FYI" (i.e., For Your Information) since I thought you might also be interested in other approaches and proofs. As for what you wrote specifically, I agree with, and don't have anything else to add, to what is in [Kavi Rama Murthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3675404/602049).

Comment: Well, I do appreciate the welcoming to SE and the other proof approach! Thanks! I will take a look at it later.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is almost perfect. But the quadratic equation gives $L=\frac {1\pm \sqrt 5} 2$. You should observe that $L =\lim a_n \geq 0$ and $\frac {1- \sqrt 5} 2<0$ so we cannot have $L=\frac {1- \sqrt 5} 2$.

Comment: Thanks! I omitted that in this proof, but I will make sure if I have another problem like this tomorrow to include your statement.